# JS working in fiddle, but not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I'm new to jquery (and js), and I've got the following fiddle, which is working fine, but I'm apparently missing something about getting it working on the site.

http://jsfiddle.net/aintnobody/70501ecr/2/

I think I'm missing something about how it's loaded on fiddle vs site.  Here is what code looks like:

```
// on initial load
$( document ).ready(function() {
    onPlayaLoad();
});

// initiate API
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// read player state
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        onPlaying();
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        onPaused();
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        onEnded();
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
        onBuffering();
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
        onCued();
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.UNSTARTED) {
        onUnstarted();
    }
}
```

Then the functions called from above are defined.  It all works just fine on the fiddle.  On my site, the first function fires fine when the document loads, but none of the player state functions do.  I cut and pasted all the js from the fiddle, and have it loading at the end of the body sectiton.  It depends on Jquery and TimelineMax.  Jquery is loaded in the head, and TimelineMax is loaded just before it included in the same minification script.

That must all be working because the first function (onPlayaLoad) is running fine and wouldn't if both jquery and TimelineMax weren't firing.

So...  Are the player state functions trying to run before the document is ready because they aren't wrapped in the on document ready function like the first fctn is?  If so, I must be nesting it incorrectly in my tests to fix this.

Any input greatly appreciated as I know I'm just a few clicks away from this functioning since it already does in fiddle.

thx

Comment: Functions don't run until you call them.

Comment: I don't know how we're supposed to guess what you're doing differently on the real site. All we can see is what you've posted here and the fiddle.

Comment: It's the same exact code, just pasted into a file, then called at the base of the body.  The question really boils down to how the fiddle calls it.  I just type the js into the fiddle and it runs, so I must be missing some aspect of that.  My guess is it has something to do with needing to wrap all the player state functions within the on document ready function, like maybe they're trying to run too early and the fiddle does that by default?  If it is helpful, I can deploy it.  I thought I was calling them above (again, working in fiddle).  If not, I need to adjust.

Comment: You can open up Developer Tools and see exactly how Fiddle calls it.

Comment: I've done that.  In viewing source, it just looks like the body html then everything inside the script tag.  In source for site, it looks like same except script in external file.  Question is do I need to do something different than fiddle for site, like wrapping all inside some kind of init function or something then calling that from the body as opposed to just linking to the file which contains all the exact same js as int the fiddle?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do anything special on your site. We really need to see what you're doing there, it's hard to tell from your description.

Comment: ok, played with it a bunch and found that for some reason GSAP script had to be loaded in head.  Not sure why, but will play with some more to find out.  Thx